# HTML thead over multiple columns

Tags: html, css

How can I get a thead th overlap, over multiple td's horizontally? `text-overflow` doesn't seem to cut it

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Post your code..... preferably as a Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th colspan="2">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kmgv5/)**